# How to replace the number occurring before a pattern using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

String: `56abc67xyz, 56abc67xyz68xyz, 12abc69xyzA`

Output: `56abcxyz, 56abc67xyzxyz, 12abc69xyzA`

So, the numbers occurring right before xyz should be removed but there shouldn't be anything after the xyz. It should be the last thing in the string.

CODE:

```
mystring.replace(/\d+xyz$/, '')
```

This code will remove the last xyz but I want to keep it as in example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Positive Lookahead: `(?=)`. So if you want to check if something is there, but not match it, put it after the `=`, like this: `\d+(?=xyz$)`

```js
console.log('56abc67xyz'.replace(/\d+(?=xyz$)/, ''))
console.log('56abc67xyz68xyz'.replace(/\d+(?=xyz$)/, ''))
console.log('12abc69xyzA'.replace(/\d+(?=xyz$)/, ''))
```

Comment: I would use \b instead of $ to capture a word boundary.

Comment: @richard good job upvoted, but I want to suggest also some little fixes if I can. 1) in the second use `/g` and not `$`. and it will be something like this `/\d+(?=xyz)/g` . `g` means `global` so it will check for multiple times (from left to right)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Why do we need to check multiple times from left to right? There is only one occurrence and it occurs at the end of the string. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @ITgoldman what is the advantage of using `\b` over `$` in this case?

Comment: just to match a few repetition of strings inside bigger text

Comment: @aste123 sorry you updated the question, before updating you writed that the result should be `56abcxyzxyz` so if also multiple xyz should be considered, but right now isn't the case. so if in you can a string like this `56abc56xyz45xyz09xyz43xyz98xyz` if will delete all numbers before the xyz and not only the last `56abcxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz`

Comment: @aste123 I don't mean multiple times from right to left. the regex with `g` will do 1 time from left to right. but it will check for multiple same pattern (so it will not see only the last, but if the the regex is true more than 1) if is matches the first time, it will try to check on his right and so on. so one time but checking from left to right (normal reading letter order)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I didn't make any edit after the answer was posted. Also the only substantial edit I had made was to add the third example. The second example shows that only one instance will be found and replaced and it was there since start. Anyway thank you :)